# Add global error in validate function

Tags: java, forms, validation, playframework-2.2

I have a login form:

```
public static class LoginForm {
    @Constraints.Required
    public String email;
    @Constraints.Required
    public String password;
}
```

And I need to validate if user exist or is validated. So my validate function is:

```
public List<ValidationError> validate() {
    List<ValidationError> errors = new ArrayList<ValidationError>();
    User user = User.findByEmail(email);
    if (user == null || !Hash.checkPassword(password, user.passwordHash)) {
        errors.add(new ValidationError("email", "Invalid email"));
        return errors;
    } else if (!user.validated) {
        errors.add(new ValidationError("email", "Not validated email"));
        return errors;
    }
     return null;
}
```

But how to make these errors global?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found out solution. I have to pass to concstuctor of ValidationError first argument as empty string. So whole code looks like:

```
public static class LoginForm {
    @Constraints.Required
    public String email;
    @Constraints.Required
    public String password;

    public List<ValidationError> validate() {
        List<ValidationError> errors = new ArrayList<ValidationError>();
        User user = User.findByEmail(email);
        if (user == null || !Hash.checkPassword(password, user.passwordHash)) {
            errors.add(new ValidationError("", "Invalid email"));
            return errors;
        } else if (!user.validated) {
            errors.add(new ValidationError("", "Not validated email"));
            return errors;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```